# Passing form input to jQuery as a variable (to prompt a value)

Tags: jquery, forms, variables, input

I have a form where users type in **start time** and **end time** of an event (for example in the format HH:mm, like 16:45).

```
<form action="time.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="start" /></td>
    <input type="text" name="end" /></td>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I would like to prompt automatically a value for end time which depends on the value typed in as start time.
Let's say I want to prompt a value (variable `$endTime`) which is 100 minutes later than start time.

I am trying using jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="start"]').change(function() {
        $('input[name="end"]').val("<?php echo $endTime ;?>");
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem with the script above is that `input[name="start"]` should be stored as a variable, in order to calculate $endTime accordingly.
Maybe you have a piece of advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the end input using jquery itself without using a variable.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="start"]').change(function() {
        $('input[name="end"]').val(computeEndTime($('input[name="start"]').val()));
    });
function computeEndTime(start){
    var hourstart = start.substr(0, start.indexOf(':'));
    var minutestart = start.substr(start.indexOf(":") + 1);
    var total = hourstart * 60 + minutestart + 100;

    var minutes = total%60;
    var hours = (total - minutes) / 60;
    return hours + ":" + minutes;
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: How can you implement that computation in jQuery?

Comment: Added the computation logic!

Comment: Thanks. I think it needs some adjustments though. If you type in the start time `09:00`, the script prompts  `900001:40` as end time.

Comment: Have to convert the substrings to int before doing math functions

Comment: `var hourstart = parseInt(ini.substr(0, ini.indexOf(':')));` and 
`var minutestart = parseInt(ini.substr(ini.indexOf(":") + 1));`